# Can't connect PyQt signal to function in custom object class

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In my main GUI, I am trying to create a custom object that copies and verifies the copy of a separate set of files. I've simplified this down to what is necessary since I have to type this code off a machine not connected to the internet.
The AppState object creates, I'm able to create the VerifyWorker object, but the finished_value_state signal never connects to AppState.set_verified. The exact error code being:
`TypeError: connect() failed between VerifyWorker.finished_value_signal[bool] and set_verified()`

Am I missing something here? Am I trying to do something that can't be done?

````
class WorkerSignal(QtCore.QObject):
    finished_value_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)

class VerifyWorker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, dir_a, dir_b)
        self(VerifyWorker, self).__init__()
        self.signals = WorkerSignal()
        self.dir_a = dir_a
        self.dir_b = dir_b

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        verified = ut.dirs_match(self.dir_a, self.dir_b)
        self.signals.finished_value_signal.emit(verified)


class AppState(object)
    def __init__(self):
        self.copy_verified = None
        self.qthreadpool = QThreadPool()
        self.verify_copy()

    def verify_copy(self):
        verify_worker = VerifyWorker(dir_a, dir_b)
        verify_worker.signals.finished_value_signal.connect(self.set_verified)
        self.qthreadpool.start(verify_worker)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def set_verified(self, verified):
        self.copy_verified = verified

class MyGui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGui, self).__init__()
        self.ui = UI_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.state = AppState()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
   try:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        ui = MyGui()
        ui.show()
        app.setActiveWindow(ui)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
   except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))```
````

Comment: PyQt decorators only make sense when used in QObject subclasses, while you're using a basic python object. Either subclass from QObject, or remove the decorator (which is normally not required).

Comment: Thank you, removing the decorator solved the issue. I am still learning how PyQt decorators work.